# Passing values to MS Access On Open events from outside code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have many MS Access reports. They show diff statistics by State. They have no recordsource property set. An "On Open" event sets the recordsource property. One of the arguments of the routine that sets the recordSource is "state". By default it's "CA".

Now I want to create an outside program that would loop through all states, and print each report for each state. My question is, how can I pass the state value to the On Open event function? Is there a way to do this?

here is my On Open report code:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
     Call createReport(Me, New C_r01_r02_Sum_for_PPO_Only)
End Sub
```

and here is the createReport code:

```
Sub createReport(rpt As Report, oRep As IReportClass, Optional rptState As String = "CA")
      'get the recordsource for the report
       rpt.recordSource = oRep.getSource(rptState)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `OpenReport` to open your reports, than you can utilize `OpenArgs` parameter of function:

`Sub OpenReport(ReportName, [View As AcView = acViewNormal], [FilterName], [WhereCondition], [WindowMode As AcWindowMode = acWindowNormal], [OpenArgs])`

And inside `Open` event of report check and use `OpenArgs` property:

```
if not Me.OpenArgs is Nothing then 
    ' do what ever you want
    ' 
end if
```